# model instance exists but is "saved" anyway

Tags: django, model, save, instance

My instance seems to be saved when I call the `save` method. The problem: the instance already exists in my database!

My model:

```
class DosIdModel(models.Model):
    dosId = models.IntegerField(max_length=7, primary_key=True)
    proposOrigine = models.CharField(max_length=4)
    proposAnnee = models.IntegerField(max_length=4)
    proposChrono = models.CharField(max_length=7)
    splitNumber = models.IntegerField(max_length=1, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
```

My view:

```
instance = DosIdModel()
instance.dosId=int(row[0])
instance.proposOrigine=row[1].strip()
instance.proposAnnee=int(row[2])
instance.proposChrono=row[3].strip()
instance.splitNumber=emptyOrVar(row[4], "int")
msg=(instance.dosId)

savedList=[]
errors_list=[]
try:
    print "exist: ", DosIdModel.objects.get(dosId=instance.dosId).dosId
    instance.save()
    print "saved"
    savedList.append(msg)
    print "end try"
except IntegrityError, e:
    print "except"
    error= "The row " + str(msg) + " already exists!!"
```

Result in the console:

```
exist:  104486
saved
end try
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Sorry, no idea what that code snippet is attempting to demonstrate.

Comment: Why is this a problem? Apparently there is already a record with that same `dosId`. So `.save()` will just update that record.

Comment: if you are working with data from forms, you would better use the integrated forms...

Comment: I thought the `save` method was for `INSERT` queries only. I use this code with an other model and it throws an `IntegrityError` if the object already exists. As pointed out by Kevin, the reason might be that I did not declare a `primary key` in my other model (I use the `auto primary key` created by Django).

Comment: So I ended up using `force_insert=True` (I don't want to do an `update`, just an `insert`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Review the documentation on [How Django knows to UPDATE vs. INSERT](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/models/instances/#how-django-knows-to-update-vs-insert). Specifically:

> If the object’s primary key attribute is set to a value that evaluates to True...
>   Django executes a SELECT query to determine whether a record with the given primary
>   key already exists. If the record with the given primary key does already exist, Django 
>   executes an UPDATE query.... The one gotcha here is that you should be careful not to 
>   specify a primary-key value explicitly when saving new objects, if you cannot guarantee
>   the primary-key value is unused.

You can get the behavior you're looking for by using `instance.save(force_insert=True)` -- that will force the INSERT which in turn should raise the `IntegrityError` you're expecting.

Note, however, that you're going against the grain. Here's what the docs say about [`force_insert`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/models/instances/#forcing-an-insert-or-update):

> It should be very rare that you’ll need to use these parameters. Django will almost
>   always do the right thing and trying to override that will lead to errors that are
>   difficult to track down. This feature is for advanced use only.

Comment: Indeed, I had misunderstood the `save` method. I use this code for many models, with different `uniqueness` constraints, so I ended up using `force_insert=True`. Seems to work :). Thank you